# Dot product of patches in tensorflow

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision, tensorflow, linear-algebra

I have two square matrices of the same size and the dimensions of a square patch. I'd like to compute the dot product between every pair of patches. Essentially I would like to implement the following operation:

```
def patch_dot(A, B, patch_dim):
    res_dim = A.shape[0] - patch_dim + 1
    res = np.zeros([res_dim, res_dim, res_dim, res_dim])
    for i in xrange(res_dim):
        for j in xrange(res_dim):
            for k in xrange(res_dim):
                for l in xrange(res_dim):
                    res[i, j, k, l] = (A[i:i + patch_dim, j:j + patch_dim] *
                                       B[k:k + patch_dim, l:l + patch_dim]).sum()

    return res
```

Obviously this would be an extremely inefficient implementation. Tensorflow's tf.nn.conv2d seems like a natural solution to this as I'm essentially doing a convolution, however my filter matrix isn't fixed. Is there a natural solution to this in Tensorflow, or should I start looking at implementing my own tf-op?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The natural way to do this is to first extract overlapping image patches of matrix B using [tf.extract_image_patches](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#extract_image_patches), then to apply the [tf.nn.conv2D](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/api_docs/python/nn.html#conv2d) function on A and each B sub-patch using [tf.map_fn](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/api_docs/python/functional_ops.html).

Note that prior to use [tf.extract_image_patches](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#extract_image_patches) and [tf.nn.conv2D](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/api_docs/python/nn.html#conv2d) you need to reshape your matrices as 4D tensors of shape `[1, width, height, 1]` using [tf.reshape](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#reshape).

Also, prior to use [tf.map_fn](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/api_docs/python/functional_ops.html), you would also need to use the [tf.transpose](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#transpose) op so that the B sub-patches are indexed by the first dimension of the tensor you use as the `elems` argument of [tf.map_fn](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/api_docs/python/functional_ops.html).